# Reactjs could not properly connect to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Reactjs could not properly connect to Nodejs

I have node js code below which works fine with jquery ajax call.  when I test the code with ajax , it shows **two** messages
**a user connected** and **helloworld message** in the console.

```
//var socket = io();
//var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected now');
    socket.on('joined', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('acknowledge', 'Acknowledged');
    });

});

http.listen(9090, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:9090');
});
```

Now I Want to run the code with **reactjs** but it partially works.

With Reactjs, I could only see a message showing
that user is connected to server but it will not show Helloworld wellcome message. When I check the console for reactjs code,

I could see **uncaught ReferenceError: socket is not defined at this line of code**

```
socket.emit('joined', 'Hello World from client ');
```

**here is the main code**

```
//npm install --save socket.io
//npm install --save socket.io-client

import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import io from "socket.io-client";


class ChatReact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};



this.socket = io('http://localhost:9090');

 this.socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        socket.emit('joined', 'Hello World from client ');
    });

this.socket.on('acknowledge', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div>


<h1> Testing Socket Io with Reactjs</h1>


        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { ChatReact };
```

Comment: At Sir matt, your suggestion will trigger an error below. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at Socket.<anonymous> .

Comment: please is there any other work around. Between thanks for response so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [socket.io - ReferenceError: socket is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604767/socket-io-referenceerror-socket-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that you actually don't have a `socket` variable defined anywhere, what you have is a `this.socket`, so a property on a class. You'll need to refer to it this way.

Second, even if you change the code to use `this.socket`, the `this` inside your callback function will not be pointing to your react class, so `this.socket` will be undefined. To fix this you will need either an arrow function or a bound regular function.

Does your environment support arrow functions? If so, changing a callback this way should do the trick:

```
this.socket.on('connect',(data) => {
    this.socket.emit('joined', 'Hello World from client ');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `socket` is not defined at all, and instead it should relate to `this.socket` (`this.socket.emit`). However, you'll have a problem because `this` will undefined in traditional function callbacks. Instead, you can do use [fat arrow functions](https://hackernoon.com/getting-to-grips-with-es6-arrow-functions-ebfa62c5c5d6) callbacks (which doesn't rebind `this`), and instead approach your "socket" connection like so:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import io from "socket.io-client";

class ChatReact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { data: {} };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const socket = io('http://localhost:9090');
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.emit('joined', 'Hello World from client ');
    });
    socket.on('acknowledge', data => {
        this.setState({ data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <h1>Testing Socket Io with Reactjs</h1>
         { JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 4) }
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ChatReact;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir matt Carlotta for responses so far but unfortunately  your he solution does not work for me at the moment. Between Thanks